# How position a div in the middle of a screen, but to move with the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My table wont position in the center of the window, and move with the document

jquery:

```
$table.css('width', $(window).width() - $("this").width() / 2)
```

html:

```
<div class="tabcon">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use css for such things. try this one.

```
.tabcon{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, by "middle of the screen" you mean both horizontally and vertically centered, you need the following settings. The absolute position and top/left settings first place the upper left *corner* of the table into the exact middle of the window, then the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` setting moves it left and up by half of the tables width and height, thereby placing the whole table into the exact middle.

Note: The vh/vw make sure it's really the middle of the screen, not of any parent element.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabcon">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>AA </td>
      <td> BB</td>
      <td> DD</td>
      <td>FF </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```